# Checking against a XML file and using attributes to check against user input value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I have a Xml file:-

```
<Users>
  <User Name="abc" Pass="asp"></User>
  <User Name="def" Pass="net"></User>
</Users>
```

I have to write a code where two user input values entered in the textbox eg:- usernm and pass are to be checked against the attribute of the particular node and its pass for returning a true value.

i want to check d inputs usernm and pass against the  attribute name which if matches will check the pass as well and return a true of fasle value.

Please suggestsomething without using iterator and inumerable.

Comment: There's nothing in this question which is ASP.NET-specific, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well LINQ to XML is pretty much based on iterators, so it's hard not to use them at all... but I suspect you want something like:

```
return doc.Descendants("User")
          .Any(x => (string) x.Attribute("Name") == targetName &&
                    (string) x.Attribute("Pass") == targetPassword);
```

Or assign it to a variable:

```
bool foundUser = doc.Descendants("User")
                    .Any(x => /* code as before */);
```

or if you *really* want it as an `if` condition:

```
if (doc.Descendants("User")
       .Any(x => /* code as before */))
{
}
```

Personally I'd *either* extract this to a separate method (which can just be the return statement as per the first example) *or* use a local variable for simplicity - I don't like my `if` conditions being this complicated.

That will determine whether any `User` element matches the relevant attributes. It doesn't give any information about the element which matched, of course. For that you'd want to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Any`, and then if the element is non-null, that's the first match.

Comment: I'll check this out. will this work with a if statement? Thank You.

Comment: @tyson: Sure - `Any()` just returns a `bool`. Will edit to make that clearer.